# How to get my JavaScript traffic lights working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing my work in JavaScript and I need to create a traffic light that will change colour every time the button is clicked. I spent a long time on it and I still cannot get it working. Can someone please have a look for me and give me some tips on how to get it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <img id="myImage" src="Light1.gif" width="500" height ="350">
      <p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Light</button>
        <p>
        <p>Click Change Light to change the traffic light.</p>
        <script>
          var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
          var p1 = new Image();
          p1.src = "Light1.gif";

          var p2=  new Image();
          p2.src = "Light2.gif";

          var p3 = new Image();
          p3.src = "Light3.gif";

          var p4 = new Image();
          p4.src = "Light4.gif";

          var imgArray = [p1,p2,p3,p4];
          var n = 0;

          function myFunction(){
            n = n + 1;
            if (n === imgArray.length) {
              n = 0
            }
            image.src = imgArray[n];
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: *every time the button is created* **or** *every time the button is clicked*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, there are syntax errors in your code which you need to check before posting. line terminator `;` is missing on most of the lines, and there's an extra brace.

For the problem, you are creating objects of type Image and then mapping it as source to the original image element which will not work. You can just create array of text values (image names), as mentioned below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <img id="myImage" src="Light1.gif" width="500" height="350">
  <p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Change Light</button>
    <p>
      <p>Click Change Light to change the traffic light.</p>
      <script>
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        var p1 = "Light1.gif";
        var p2 = "Light2.gif";
        var p3 = "Light3.gif";
        var p4 = "Light4.gif";
        var imgArray = [p1, p2, p3, p4];
        var n = 0;

        function myFunction() {
          n = n + 1;
          if (n == imgArray.length) {
            n = 0
          };
          image.src = imgArray[n];
        }
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Pro Tip**: indent your code for better readability

Comment: I finally got it working. Thank you soooooooo much. I have spent so many hours on it already and it finally works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I think you are trying to do something like below:

**Corrections in your code**:

1. remove extra closing bracket `}`
2. Append `.src` 
   image.src = imgArray[n].src;

```js
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
var p1 = new Image()
p1.src = "Light1.gif"
var p2=  new Image()
p2.src = "Light2.gif"
var p3 = new Image()
p3.src = "Light3.gif"
var p4 = new Image()
p4.src = "Light4.gif"
var imgArray = [p1,p2,p3,p4];
var n = 0;
function myFunction(){
n = n + 1;
if(n == imgArray.length){
n = 0};
image.src = imgArray[n].src;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="myImage" src="Light1.gif" width="500" height ="350">
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Change Light</button><p>
<p> Click Change Light to change the traffic light. </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As spidey said, you are mapping image object to src of another image.

You can also just replace the line inside your loop with:

image.src = imageArray[n].src;

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the

```
var p1 = new Image()
p1.src = "Light1.gif"
```

All what you need is

```
var p1 = "Light1.gif"
```

See My [CodePen](http://codepen.io/romankoval10/pen/MebjYj).

**Make Sure To Remember Your Semicolons At The End of Lines**

Comment: @Spidey I updated my answer, thanks.